# No operator "+" matches these operands

Tags: c++

```
for (TPathInfoList::iterator iter = pathInfoList.begin(); iter != pathInfoList.end(); ++iter)
{
    const TPathInfoList::value_type& path = *iter;

    EResult resultCode = MakeMSA(path, &msg);
    fs::path parentPath = path.parent_path();
    std::string shortPath = parentPath.parent_path().filename() + "\\" + parentPath.filename() + "\\" + path.filename();;

    tm t;
    time_t timer;
    timer = time(NULL);
    localtime_s(&t, &timer);

    printf("%04d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d [%s] %s\n", 
        t.tm_year + 1900, t.tm_mon + 1, t.tm_mday, t.tm_hour, t.tm_min, t.tm_sec,
        msg.c_str(), shortPath.c_str());
}
```

I'm try boost 1.60 and i'm stuck to this error.
What i'm doing wrong?
http://prntscr.com/a2yync

Comment: Try wrapping your components of your string with std::string()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe error message screenshot shows that `parentPath.parent_path().filename()` is not a string but a [`filesystem::path`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#class-path).

As `shortPath` is a `string`, I'd suggest to  `parentPath.parent_path().filename().string`:

```
std::string shortPath = parentPath.parent_path().filename().string() 
          + "\\" + parentPath.filename().string() 
          + "\\" + path.filename().string();
```

or to make `shortPath` a `path` and use concatenation with `+=` operator

Comment: THANKS. You are the best. :d  Wich method do you think it's good ?

Comment: If you want to use it as a path, I'd rather go for the second option.  I would even use operator `/=` to append the additional components without the `\\`.  This has the advantage of being more portable (because /= will add an intermediary  `/`  on POSIX and a `\` on windows)